# Installing Flac command line tool on Windows

Tags: python, windows, raspberry-pi

### Situation

I am trying to make [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) work in Python.

- OS: Windows 10
- System: RaspBerry PI 4 4GB
- Python Version: 3.9.0 32bit

#### Source code

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.pause_threshold = 0.5
    voice = r.listen(source)
    command = r.recognize_google(voice, language="nl-NL")
    command = command.lower()
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.5)
```

#### Output

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\user\user-master\userv2\user\Static>py test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\user\user-master\userv2\user\Static\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    command = r.recognize_google(voice, language="nl-NL")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 826, in recognize_google
    flac_data = audio_data.get_flac_data(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 445, in get_flac_data
    flac_converter = get_flac_converter()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 1196, in get_flac_converter
    raise OSError("FLAC conversion utility not available - consider installing the FLAC command line application by running `apt-get install flac` or your operating system's equivalent")
OSError: FLAC conversion utility not available - consider installing the FLAC command line application by running `apt-get install flac` or your operating system's equivalent
```

So I downloaded Flac from https://xiph.org/flac/download.
I installed the latest version for Windows. Next, I unzipped the file and ran the 64-bit .exe files and 32-bit .exe files.

When I type 'Flac' in the command prompt, It says:

```
'flac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Do I need to add Flac to my System Environment Variables? If yes how so? If not; what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. Finally I resolved using the following steps:

1. Go to [flac download](https://xiph.org/flac/download.html) page
2. Choose OS (Windows, in your case)
3. Download `win.zip` version (latest), probably at the end of the page. I downloaded [this one (1.3.4-win.zip)](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/xiph/releases/flac/flac-1.3.4-win.zip)
4. Move to the download directory and extract it (You can simple use `Extract Here`)
5. Move to `win64` or `win32` according to your system architecture
6. Copy `flac.exe` and paste it inside `C:\Windows\System32` this directory.

Try running your code. If it executes successfully, No need to do last step. If not, perform 7th step too.

7. Remove `.exe` .i.e. Rename it to `flac`

I had to perform the last step too. That's all

Comment: The step 7 solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This solved everything, works both on Windows and MacOS:

Type this in Terminal or Command Prompt:

```
brew install flac
```

***brew*** worked rather than ***pip3*** in my case.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

After some [research](https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php?topic=63815.0) I found that you can put the .exe file in your C:\Windows\System32 folder in order to use flac command tools in the command prompt.

Answer (score -2):

> Try this code

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from time import ctime
import os
import playsound 
from gtts import gTTS

def speak(audioString):
    tts = gTTS(text=audioString, lang='en')
    tts.save("audio.mp3")
    playsound.playsound("audio.mp3", True)
    os.remove("audio.mp3")

def recordAudio():
    # Record Audio
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Say somthing...")
        audio = r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=2)

    data = ""
    try:
        data = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said: " + data)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

    return data

def jarvis(data):
    if "how are you" in data:
        speak("I am fine")

    if "what time" in data:
        speak(ctime())

speak("Hi Osama, what can I do for you?")

while True:
    data = recordAudio()
    jarvis(data)
```

Comment: ok, the problem with your devise not code

Comment: I using Linux I don't know about windows so sorry!

Comment: *"Try this code"* is not an answer to any question.