# FLAC conversion utility not available - consider installing the FLAC command line application on Spyder/Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, speech-recognition, spyder, flac

I'm working on a speech recognition and following the example shown in [this PythonCode page](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/using-speech-recognition-to-convert-speech-to-text-python) on Windows 10 with Spyder 5.1.5/Anaconda (Python 3.8.10).

I installed `SpeechRecognition` and `pydub` with `conda install -c conda-forge`, and when I run the following script:

```
with sr.AudioFile(filename) as source:
    audio_data = r.record(source)
    text = r.recognize_google(audio_data)
    print(text)
```

or more specifically (`text = r.recognize_google(audio_data)`), this error message shows up:

```
OSError: FLAC conversion utility not available - consider installing the FLAC command line application by running `apt-get install flac` or your operating system's equivalent
```

[There's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737909/flac-conversion-utility-not-available-consider-installing-the-flac-command-lin) but I couldn't find the solution for the Windows environment where I don't have `apt-get install flac` or `brew`.

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65939571/installing-flac-command-line-tool-on-windows), I've downloaded the flac.exe file and placed under `C:\Windows\System32`. I can run flac on command line, but the same error shows up when I run the python script.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/c89856088ad81d81d38be314e3db50905481c5fe/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L1395) it is searching for a *flac* without *exe* extension that will not work in Windows. If that fails it looks for a file with a specific name (**flac-win32.exe**) in module folder.

You can either try to remove the extension of the file in the *System32* folder or put the file in the module folder.

Comment: Thanks! I removed the extension (changed `flac.exe` to `flac`) in `C:\Windows\System32` and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

viilpe's answer is correct, and would have worked for me except for the fact that my Windows computer refused to rename the file as just 'flac'.

I ran pretty much this exact speech recognition code in Spyder, but I kept getting the same error as alpha. I tried viilpe's solution, but it still didn't work for me. I don't know if something has updated or changed between now and 2017, but even though I put the flac file in my System32 folder and renamed it flac, my computer still treated it as being named 'flac.exe'. I had to edit the source code, changing the line:

```
def get_flac_converter():
"""Returns the absolute path of a FLAC converter executable, or raises an OSError if none can be found."""
flac_converter = shutil_which("flac")  # check for installed version first
```

to:

```
def get_flac_converter():
"""Returns the absolute path of a FLAC converter executable, or raises an OSError if none can be found."""
flac_converter = shutil_which("flac.exe")  # check for installed version first
```

This allowed the module to find my flac file. For reference, these are lines 1094 - 1096 in the **init**.py file for the speech_recognition module.

So, for anyone getting this error in 2022 or later, and renaming your flac file doesn't work, try this.